# DotNetCore SocketException "Cannot assign requested address" SmtpClient

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-5, amazon-eks

I have an dotnet 5 service that sends emails using the SmtpClient. This service is deployed as a linux docker image running in AWS EKS (Kubernetes).

Running locally on my machine, everything works fine, but when it's deployed to our K8s environment, every SmtpClient.SentAsync call sits for around 10 minutes, before it finally crashes with the following exception:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address

I've researched this error, and there is a lot of talk about using/not using localhost as a host name. In my case, I'm not using local host at all. I'm just trying to send outbound emails using SmtpClient, where the host is a 3rd party SMTP server.

I've tried running this as a linux docker container on my own dev machine, and it also works fine, so it seems to not like something about my EKS environment, yet I can't figure out what that is. Any ideas?

Update:
FYI, the pod can access the internet just fine, using the HttpClient for example. I can also make http calls to it's API on port 80. So it's binding just fine in that regard. It just seems to be an issue when using the SmtpClient.

Stack Track:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.PostOneBeginConnect(MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoMultipleAddressConnectCallback(Object result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.MultipleAddressConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.InitializeConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   ...
```

Comment: Have you checked if inside the EKS env the SMTP server hostname is resolved on another address?

Comment: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address` - your app failed while trying to bind to the container IP? If true, do you know if the port is already in used within the pod?

Comment: @Max, It resolves to several IP addresses (It's Office 365), but it resolves the same way my local machine does.

Comment: @gohm'c, The app appears to bind just fine, and to be clear, it can access the internet just fine, and I can access it's API hosted on port 80. It just seems to be an issue when using the SmtpClient.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different SMTP client? You have to anyway. SmtpClient is considered obsolete and even the docs suggest using MailKit instead. SmptClient doesn't support any of the newer security protocols

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the suggestion. With setting the port and SecureSocketOptions.StartTls, looks like it's working. Thanks for the help. Not sure why it works in every case except in AWS, but it works!